# Failed to build module 'XXX' from its module interface while creating xcframework

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

Currently I am working in a framework project to distribute to a client we have. The Framework has SPM dependencies and I wanted to create an XCFramework from it. I found the scripts to archive and generate the XCFramework with the `xcodebuild` tool. The problem is that the generation is not working and I get the following error `Failed to build module 'XXX' from its module interface; it may have been damaged or it may have triggered a bug in the Swift compiler when it was produced`. I don't know if it is possible to build a framework with SPM dependencies as an XCFramework I was trying to distribute it as binary framework to protect our source code. I previously looked for this but couldn't found any information in the matter. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I'm facing the same problems. Have you found a solution? If so I would be very interested in some informations.

Answer (score 9):

One solution seems to add `@_implementationOnly import` for the modules from the third-party SDKs. This should fix your XCframework error if you aren't using anything from that SDK as part of your module's public interface.

Comment: I would like to write this comment to thank you for saving me. Is there some documentation explaining why I need to use `@_implementationOnly` in this case and what are the other cases I should use it?

Comment: @alobaili: you can find a few discussion about this topic on the swift forums. [implementation](https://forums.swift.org/t/update-on-implementation-only-imports/26996). [Issue with third party](https://forums.swift.org/t/issue-with-third-party-dependencies-inside-a-xcframework-through-spm/41977)

Comment: My xcframework does not depend on any third party dependency. I am still getting the error shown in question.