# Swift XCFramework compile issue - arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface : No such module 'Firebase'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, terminal, xcframework

We created one of our custom frameworks as ABCSDK.xcframework to support both Simulator and Device versions. We created the xcframework through Terminal with archive files of both Simulator and Device. When we use the ABCSDK.xcframework in the client project, we are getting the below error,

```
arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface

arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface:19:8 No such module 'Firebase'

Failed to build module ‘ABCSDK' for importation due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
```

Could you please help here to resolve the issue? We are using the Xcode version 14.1 and we did "Embed & Sign" in capabilities. We tried by removing the Firebase dependencies from Pods as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you didn't test the integration of your framework with the actual app, customer did for you. I suggest creating a new app and properly testing it with your framework. And yes, ideally your framework should not depend on 3rd-party frameworks, but if it does, it needs to express them properly as dependencies (e.g. in podspec)

Comment: @rapiddevice yes, we are testing the xcframework in our internal project. Yes, we updated the pod spec of the 3rd party frameworks used in cocoapod. Could u pls help? Thanks.

Comment: Not really - too many possibilities on how the project is setup and what can go wrong. Main thing is you need to provide your module with some clues on how to locate Firebase. Sometimes it's done in podspec, sometimes in Podfile (depends on the whole setup). Also how Firebase is imported: e.g. in ObjC sometimes it's just the matter of changing `@import Firebase` to `#import <Firebase/...>`

Comment: @Yuvaraj.M, did you managed to find any solution?

Comment: @Yuvaraj.M any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The swiftinterface file had the line `import Alamofire` and it could't find the Alamofire library but when I imported it it worked. So, the solution I found to this was making the libraries not visible for swiftinterface file with `@_implementationOnly import Alamofire`.
[Failed to build module 'XXX' from its module interface while creating xcframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65633420/failed-to-build-module-xxx-from-its-module-interface-while-creating-xcframewor?rq=3)